# Variable from livewire is not passing component

Tags: laravel-livewire

I tried passing a variable from livewire component:

```
class Index extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.index')->with('type', config('constants.NONAUTH'));
    }
}
```

and accessing it from layouts.app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

{{dd($type)}}

@include('includes.head')
```

I get an error that $type is not defined, what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: I’m trying to include certa[i](https://alightmotionapk.co/mod/)n styles in the head tag based on type. I’ve gone ahead with using custom layouts instead: laravel-livewire.com/docs/rendering-components#custom-layout

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as an array instead.

```
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.index')->with(['type' => config('constants.NONAUTH')]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is a strange use case, you'd usually render a livewire component as a subcomponent of some view.
You might want to take a look at this section [full page componenets](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#page-components)

It could clear up some questions you might have, a normal subcomponent in livewire can access variables within a div - that's why the artisan generated component has this out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your `$type` variable to your Livewire component, yet trying to access it inside a blade file. If you want it in your blade file, you need to pass it from wherever you're loading the view from (e.g. a controller), or using a view composer.

However, you're not even rendering your Livewire component either. Perhaps get a read in the [docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components);

You can render a component as follows:

```html
{{-- Replace {namespace} with the kebab cased namespace of your component --}}
<livewire:{namespace}.index/>
```